# What does it mean that a fetched property is static and not dynamically updating itself?

Tags: iphone, core-data, fetched-property

Apple says in the NSFetchedPropertyDescription class reference:

> Note, however, that unlike a playlist
>   a fetched property is static—it does
>   not dynamically update itself as
>   objects in the destination entity
>   change.

Nice, but what exactly does that mean: static property? Not dynamically updating in the destination entity change?

Can someone explain that?

What I get in my head is that a fetched property is for weak references. Like: A playlist may reference songs, but the playlist doesnt "own" them. If the playlist gets deleted, the song's never get deleted as a consequence of that. Also, the songs have no back-reference to the playlist, they don't have to know that it even exists.

Ok, so if a song gets deleted, the playlist isn't notified in any way? Or what is Apple trying to tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially it means that you have to manually update the fetched result every time to receive the latest changes of your source object.

I just consulted your quoted documentation. The next paragraph after your quote should make it clear:

> The effect of a fetched property is
>   similar to executing a fetch request
>   yourself and placing the results in a
>   transient attribute, although with the
>   framework managing the details. In
>   particular, a fetched property is not
>   fetched until it is requested, and the
>   results are then cached until the
>   object is turned into a fault. You use
>   refreshObject:mergeChanges:
>   (NSManagedObjectContext) to manually
>   refresh the properties—this causes the
>   fetch request associated with this
>   property to be executed again when the
>   object fault is next fired.